# Add value to valid dataframe and ignore invalid parsing

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In a large amount of dataframe (sample as shown after), I would like to add a specified value into each valid parsing under `'timestamp'` column. However, the *timestamp* dataframe includes both numeric values and strings. I would like to remain the original strings in the dataframe.

```
,Date,Time,Company,AV_ID,timestamp
0,29-Jan-2019,09:29:43.184,DEL,DEL0002,1548754413425000000
1,29-Jan-2019,09:29:43.184,in,msg:,should
2,29-Jan-2019,09:29:43.199,DEL,DEL0002,1548754413425000000
3,29-Jan-2019,09:29:43.199,in,msg:,should
4,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.543,DEL,DEL0002,1548754415425000000
5,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.543,in,msg:,should
6,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.574,DEL,DEL0002,1548754415425000000
7,29-Jan-2019,09:29:44.574,in,msg:,should
8,29-Jan-2019,09:29:46.606,DEL,DEL0002,1548754417425000000
```

I am currently using the following code. However, I could not skip the operation for dataframe with strings. If I were to use `errors='coerce'`, I will lose my dataframe that contains the strings.

```
local = 28800000
orig_data['timestamp'] = pd.to_numeric(orig_data['timestamp'], errors = 'ignore')
orig_data['timestamp'] = orig_data['timestamp'] + local
orig_data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(orig_data['timestamp'], unit = 'ms')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `errors = 'coerce'` and in final replace missing values by original values:

```
local = 28800000
s = pd.to_numeric(orig_data['timestamp'], errors = 'coerce') + local
#change unit to ns
orig_data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(s, unit = 'ns').fillna(orig_data['timestamp'])

print (orig_data)
          Date          Time Company    AV_ID                      timestamp
0  29-Jan-2019  09:29:43.184     DEL  DEL0002  2019-01-29 09:33:33.453799936
1  29-Jan-2019  09:29:43.184      in     msg:                         should
2  29-Jan-2019  09:29:43.199     DEL  DEL0002  2019-01-29 09:33:33.453799936
3  29-Jan-2019  09:29:43.199      in     msg:                         should
4  29-Jan-2019  09:29:44.543     DEL  DEL0002  2019-01-29 09:33:35.453799936
5  29-Jan-2019  09:29:44.543      in     msg:                         should
6  29-Jan-2019  09:29:44.574     DEL  DEL0002  2019-01-29 09:33:35.453799936
7  29-Jan-2019  09:29:44.574      in     msg:                         should
8  29-Jan-2019  09:29:46.606     DEL  DEL0002  2019-01-29 09:33:37.453799936
```